# nHibernate Zero or One to one using mapping by code

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am modelling a person and a death certificate where a person can have zero or one death certificates. If I have:

```
public class Person
{
  public string PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual DeathCertificate { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class DeathCertificate
{
  public string DeathCertificateId { get; set; }
  public string PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Person { get; set; }
}
```

Where DeathCertificateId is the primary key of DeathCertificate in the database.

With the following in the mapping for the person:

```
  this.OneToOne(
    entity => entity.DeathCertificate,
    mapper =>
    {
      mapper.Access(Accessor.Property);
      mapper.Cascade(Cascade.Detach | Cascade.Persist);
      mapper.PropertyReference(p => p.Person);
      mapper.Constrained(false);
    });
```

And this for the death certificate:

```
  this.ManyToOne(
    entity => entity.Person,
    mapper =>
    {
      mapper.Column("PERSON_ID");
      mapper.Cascade(Cascade.None);
      mapper.Unique(true);
    });
```

Unfortunately, this generates SQL similar to the following whenever I query person whether I join it in or not:

```
select ...
from person p
left outer join deathcertificate dc
   on dc.person_id = p.person_id
where p.person_id = 'ABC123'
```

So it all works, but I only want a death certificate when I explicitly join it in.

I think I've got something wrong in my mappings. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

```
mapper.Constrained(false);
```

to

```
mapper.Constrained(true);
```

on the DeathCertificate mapping fixed my problem.

See https://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one for details.